# Fading images with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I am sure this is a stupid question but I am very new to actionscript.  I just need it to load some images from a folder into an array and when the user presses a button it goes through the image array and shows each image, fading the old one out as the new one comes in, stopping when each image has been seen once.  I don't even know where to start so some advice would be awesome thanks!

Comment: FYI, this would be called a slide-show :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at tweening libraries, such as [Desuade...](http://desuade.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`var yourVariable: Tween = new Tween (yourObject, "alpha",None.easeOut,1,0,2,true);`

`None.easeOut` can be `Strong.easeOut` or `Strong.easeIn`. It's the animation easing.
The end values are `start value`, `end value`, `time`, `true=seconds`, `false=frames` for the timing.